# Not able to upload multiple files in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

When I try to upload multiple files, I can't do this

**Model File**:

```
namespace app\models;
class ImageFiles extends \yii\base\Model 
{
  public $imageFiles;

  public function rules() 
  {
    return [[
      ['imageFiles'], 
      'file', 
      'skipOnEmpty'=>false, 
      'extensions'=>'jpg, png', 
      'maxFiles'=>4
    ]];
  }
}
```

**View File**

```
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm; 

$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); 

echo  $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple'=>true, 'accept'=>'image/*']); 

echo  \yii\helpers\Html::submitButton('Submit',['class'=>'btn btn-success']);

ActiveForm::end();
```

**Controller File**

```
namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;

class ImageFilesController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new \app\models\ImageFiles();
        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){

            $model->imageFiles = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'imageFiles');

            print_r($model->imageFiles);

            return;
        }
        return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
    }
}
```

`print_r($model->imageFiles)` show me nothing and no errors, because `$model->imageFiles` has no value. but when I use `print_r($_FILES)` It prints all images details. I got confused I did what the Yii documentation said but it is not working.

Comment: `$form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')` I think it should be without `[]`

Comment: I try to upload mutliple files, it works with single file upload But it would not work with multiple files

Comment: Oh yea, you right. Then I think it should be `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances()` instead of `\yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstance()` in your controller

Comment: Thanks for your rely, it worked

Answer (score 1):

For multiple files use [UploadedFile::getInstances()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile#getInstances()-detail)

```
class ImageFilesController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new \app\models\ImageFiles();
        if(Yii::$app->request->isPost){

            $model->imageFiles = \yii\web\UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');

            print_r($model->imageFiles);

            return;
        }
        return $this->render('index', ['model'=>$model]);
    }
}
```